# Considering the complex number $z = m+i$ for which values of $m$ do we have $ \left|\overline{z}+\frac{2}{z}\right| \ge 1 $

Tags: complex-numbers

Good evening to everyone. I have the following problem that I tried to solve but my mathematical instinct tells me that I didn't solve it right:

Considering the complex number $z = m+i$ for which values of $m$ do we have: $$ \left|\overline{z}+\frac{2}{z}\right| \ge 1 $$

Here's what I've tried: $$ \left|\overline{z}+\frac{2}{z}\right| \ge 1 \rightarrow \left|m-i+\frac{2}{m+i}\right|\ge 1 \rightarrow \left|\frac{m^2-1}{m+i}\right|\ge 1 \rightarrow -1\le \frac{m^2-1}{m+i}\le 1 \rightarrow\begin {cases} -1\le m^2-1\le  1 \\ -1\le m+i\le 1 \end{cases}\rightarrow \begin{cases} m \in [-2,2] \\ m \in [-1-i,1-i] \end{cases} $$

Comment: The statement $m \in [-1-i,1-i]$ doesn't make sense.Is m real? Moreover,shouldn't it be $m^2+3  $

Comment: @TushantMittal thanks for correcting me, I did some mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have mistakes ,it should be $$\left| \overline { z } +\frac { 2 }{ z }  \right| \ge 1\rightarrow \left| m-i+\frac { 2 }{ m+i }  \right| \ge 1\rightarrow \left| \frac { m^{ 2 }+3 }{ m+i }  \right| \ge 1\rightarrow \frac { \left| { m }^{ 2 }+3 \right|  }{ \sqrt { { m }^{ 2 }+1 }  } \ge 1\\ { m }^{ 2 }+3\ge \sqrt { { m }^{ 2 }+1 } \Rightarrow { m }^{ 4 }+5{ m }^{ 2 }+8\ge 0 $$ which true for  all real $m$

Comment: Sorry can I ask you how did you arrive from $ \left|m+i\right| $ to $ \sqrt{m^2+1} $ in the denominator?

Comment: Assuming m is real

Comment: @T4yl0r yes,indeed

Comment: I still can't find a way to arrive from $ \left|m+i\right| $ to $ \sqrt{m^2+1} $.. You didn;t amplify so I don't find a way to transform the first expression in the second one.

Comment: @T4yl0r,it is a absolute value of complex number ,you know it ,remember $z=a+ib,\left| z \right| =\left| a+ib \right| =\sqrt { { a }^{ 2 }+{ b }^{ 2 } } $

Comment: @Battani thanks now I got it

Comment: thus i wrote "it is true for all real m".note that if $a{ x }^{ 2 }+bx+c\ge 0,\Delta <0$ then equation holds for all real $x$

Answer (score 1):

$$\left|\bar{z}+\frac{2}{z}\right| = \frac{|z|^2 +2}{|z|} = |z|+\frac{2}{|z|} $$
By, AM-GM,
$$ |z|+\frac{2}{|z|} \geq 2\sqrt{2}  \geq 1$$
Hence, the inequality is true for all z and hence all m.

Comment: (+1) don't know why I didn't see yours before I posted. I hope you don't mind my edit.

Comment: Thanks.I definitely don't mind it.